# Assigning and using jquery with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two peices of code. One produces the desired result the other one doesnt.

Works:

```
$("#inBox" + mesh.id).html(mesh.text);
```

Doesn't work:

```
var inbox = $("#inBox" + mesh.id);
inbox.html(mesh.text);
```

Could someone please explain to me why one produces the desired result and the other one doesn't do anything?

edit: removed typo quote mark.

edit2: heres the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ntkachov/zXGjb/

edit3: Hmmm.... It works inside the fiddle but not inside my code. Ill take a look at what else might be affecting this.

Comment: Are you seeing the extra quotation mark?

Comment: Keep the JavaScript error console open. The error messages are displayed there.

Comment: Sorry about the extra quote. That was an artifact from copy-paste.

Comment: Please show a complete example that displays the problem, preferably a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as well.

Comment: @ntkachov - I just tried the code and it works fine for me, you will have to show a complete example.

Comment: added a fiddle. Please tell me if it works on your machines because it could be a local problem.

Comment: @ntkachov - I don't get it, your fiddle works fine? Check this updated version http://jsfiddle.net/zXGjb/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/FuQ72/) that shows your example. It works fine for both cases.

Comment: Check out the fiddle i made. Because yours does work but mine fails on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
inbox.html(mesh.text");
```

Should be:

```
inbox.html(mesh.text);
```

Comment: My bad that was a copy-paste typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing " after mesh.text

```
inbox.html(mesh.text");
```

This should do it:

```
inbox.html(mesh.text);
```

**Edit:**

Added a fiddle for demonstration: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coffe_e/HqBDR/)

Comment: My bad that was a type from copy pasteing the actual code doesnt have that.

Comment: @ntkachov In that case, your example should work fine, as long as your mesh.text variable is a string containing html. What does it contain?

Comment: Its just a string "my string"